# Return matching text value in cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a sheet of products and skus - I would like to have a formula that searches the entire column for matching text strings and returns it in a separate cell as the text string

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a FILTER with COUNTIF

```
=UNIQUE(
  FILTER(
   B28:B,
   COUNTIF(B28:B,B28:B)>1))
```

If you wanted to also return the name, change the first range in the FILTER to A28:B

Since it will return every instance, we need to wrap it in UNIQUE.

For an overall count,

```
=QUERY(
  {A28:B},
  "select Col1, Col2, Count(Col1)
   where Col2 is not null
   group by Col1, Col2
   label
    Col1 'Item',
    Col2 'SKU',
    Count(Col1) 'Total'")
```

This will do both the name and the SKU. If you only want to run the SKU

```
=QUERY(
  {B28:B},
  "select Col1, Count(Col1)
   where Col1 is not null
   group by Col1
   label
    Col1 'SKU',
    Count(Col1) 'Total'")
```

If you only want to pull the ones where you have more than one and want to use QUERY, you could use this or wrap the previous QUERY with another QUERY and use `where Col2 >1` -- but this one is cleaner.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  QUERY(
   UNIQUE({B2:B,COUNTIF(B2:B,B2:B)}),
   "where Col2 >1
    label
     Col1 'Item',
     Col2 'Total'"))
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! 

Say with a larger amount of data - would there be a way to return how many times a specific string is repeated 

For example white-socks has been in the column 8 times?

Comment: Definitely, @magelincs! I added them to my post. If these work out for you, can you mark it as answered? I need some of that hot reputation so I can vote on stuff :) QUERY is definitely worth getting good at. Its a database language and is perfect for stuff like this.

Comment: Wow that's perfcect thank you! Have marked as answered now - thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help. Thanks for helping out with this rep thing. I'm new and powerless.

Comment: No worries! I'm sure you'll quickly get more rep with help like that! 

One last thing I've just noticed if you don't mind haha - with the QUERY formula - what should I change to ensure the query only returns result where the SKU occurs twice - it currently returns values even with just 1 occurence

Sorry to bother you again haha

Comment: no prob. You can either wrap it with another QUERY or use an array with the SKU and the output of a COUNTIF in the second column. Wrap that with UNIQUE and run it through a QUERY to pull items where the second column is greater than 1. I added this to the post above. Its basically the same output as the filter, but with headers defined in the formula.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot Tom!

Comment: no problemo., Have a good one!